# Finding Code coverage for Spring boot application by running Functional automation test execution (not unit tests)

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, jacoco-plugin

Generally we find code coverage with unit tests using Jacoco and unit test cases however My Dev manager asking if we can use the existing functional automation tests to find the code coverage of the spring boot application. My functional tests using testng/restassured and stored in a separate code repo, not with in development source code repo.

Please suggest how can be this done if it is really possible. Appreciate if anyone can guide and share links for reference.

Thanks.